# The content returned by requests.get(URL) does not match with the content on the webpage, why is that?

Tags: url, cookies, python-requests, screen-scraping, python-requests-html

I'm trying to learn web scraping but when I try to request this page using

url = https://fbref.com/en/players/fa/

page = requests.get(url)

the page resembles what I'd get if I went one step down in the URL (https://fbref.com/en/players/), i.e. not including the "fa/"

My guess would be that this redirection has got to do with cookies or something similar, is there a way to bypass this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no issue with me. https://prnt.sc/1mc5s8z

Comment: Silly me forgot to .lower() the appendix string so my url was actually [...]/Fa/